# What's the best pattern for logging data on a Stateful Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, logging

Currently I'm thinking about adding a json array column (I'm using postgres) and just pumping log messages for the object into this attribute.  I want to log progress (The object is an import report that does a lot of stuff and takes a while so it's useful to have a sense of what's currently happening - how many rows have been imported, how many rows have been normalized, etc -

The other option is to add one of the gems that allow you to see logs streamed in a view, but this I think isn't as useful since what I'm looking for is something where I can see the history of this specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `json` column or `json[]` (PostgreSQL array of `json`) is a *very* bad idea for logging.

Each time you update it, the whole column contents must be read, modified in memory, and written out again in their entirety.

Instead, create a table used for logs for objects of this kind, with a FK to the table being logged and a timestamp for each entry. Insert a row for each log entry.

BTW, if the report runs in a single transaction, other clients won't be able to see any of the log rows until the whole view commits, in which case it won't be good for progress monitoring, but neither will your original idea. You'll need to use `NOTICE` messages instead.